# Changing date adding it into a file

Tags: cmd

I have a batch file, it's adding a text line every day (see below) to a csv file.
In the line there is a date, this date has to be changed each day and it's has to be the date of yesterday. And on Monday it's has to be the date of Friday. When the date change is done, the line has to be added in the file.

I don't know how to do it, i know there are commando's to change date. I have searched on internet and on this forum but i could not find it. Hope that some body can help me.

for %%j in (C:\blp\bbdl_csv\dailycurrency1.out.????????.csv) do @echo."EUR CMPN Curncy|0|4|EUR|12/03/2012|Composite(NY)|1.000000|">> %%j

Answer (score 0):

I would use a date library from another language to calculate the date.

Working with dates is hard to get right. For example, what happens if this runs on a weekend?

Here's an example in python.

```
import datetime

def previous_workday(date):
    day_name = date.strftime('%A')
    days_offset = 3 if day_name == 'Monday' else 1
    previous_workday = date - datetime.timedelta(days=days_offset)
    return previous_workday.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

print(previous_workday(datetime.date.today()))
```

There are Batch Libraries with date functions.

- http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdfuncs/dandt/index.html
- http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetiment.php#Yesterday

But they are much hard to control.